# Equivalent for validateRequest in mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am reading here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx#paght000004_step1 on the very first step in your machine.config  to set:

```
<system.web>
  <pages buffer="true" validateRequest="true" />
</system.web>
```

Is this already handled in mvc3 with the [Authorize] filter? or should i still put this in my web.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attribute:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Index(string InputText)
{
    return View();
}
```

Also look at this article: [Understanding Request Validation in ASP.NET MVC 3](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/02/19/understanding-request-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx)

Comment: so by default it already validates the input, with or without the web.config change?  If you want to not validate the input then you can use what you have written above?

Comment: @anthonypliu By default validation is enabled and if you post for example `html`, you will get exception `A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client`

Answer (score 0):

With [Authorize] filter you restrict access for specific action/controller to selected users and roles.

Request validation basically asserts that values submitted in action are not potentially harmful html strings (putting them un-encoded back to page could be dangerous). You can control request validation on global level with configuration files by attribute validateRequest="true/false". You may override configuration file setting with an action filter ([ValidateInput(true/false)]) (there are some other options, too).

Surely, you can relate those two things, they are both some type of validation and security mechanisms. Still, they are both very different type of validation, and you should see them as rather independent things.

Looking back to your question, you should rather put validateRequest="true" in web.config (so you will have request validation regardless of machine.config setting).